# One disk of a software RAID10 was repartitioned. What to do?

Tags: linux, software-raid

I have a software array in one machine

```
root@c ~# mdadm --query --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 17 10:22:38 2014
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 976772096 (931.52 GiB 1000.21 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 488386048 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Jan 19 10:30:49 2015
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : far=2
     Chunk Size : 256K

           UUID : e21d2907:a7b46e36:220b319d:884b2099
         Events : 0.296

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
       1       8       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
       2       8       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
       3       8       80        3      active sync   /dev/sdf
```

md0 is a RAID-10 array. A coworker made a fdisk on /dev/sdf and created three linux partitions there. Currently md0 is working fine, but I'm worried what will happen when the server will be restarted.

Is my information safe? Does the fdisk destroyed one of the pair of RAID1? **How to fix sdf without damaging the array?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your information is not safe; you have destroyed one disk in the array and it will not come up on reboot.  Your kernel will likely still be using the old partition table, because it was in use when the fdisk was done, but you need to take these steps:

1. Back up your data (it should go without saying, but I want to make it clear that I take no responsibility if this procedure doesn't work ;-)
2. Fail the disk: `mdadm --fail /dev/md0 /dev/sdf`

   - The array should now show as degraded in `/proc/mdstat`
3. Remove the disk from the array: `mdadm --remove /dev/md0 /dev/sdf`

   - The disk should now have disappeared from `/proc/mdstat`
4. Clear the partition table: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdf bs=1k count=1`
5. Re-add the disk to the array: `mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdf`
6. The array should now be rebuilding.  Monitor `/proc/mdstat` until complete.
7. Back up your data again to a different location. Compare it with the first backup and ensure that only new/updated files have changed.

You should be able to do all of the above while the array is online, because RAID 10 means that you have at least 2 copies of every block.

What your coworker did to the array is a good reason for not using raw disks in RAID arrays.  For future arrays, you should create a partition on each disk of type FD so that the system knows they are RAID partitions and anyone who comes along will see partitions on it.  You only lose a tiny amount of space and you gain a really big red flag that tells people that the disk is in use.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, Paul! I will follow dutifully your advice. From now on, only RAID in partitions.  Thanks again!